# Inject different values of enum for Junit test

Tags: spring, junit

I have a autowired bean defined in a class I want to test:

```
@Autowired
ContextEnum myContext;
```

Which is used later:

```
if(ContextEnum.A.equals(myContext)) {
// do something
} else if(ContextEnum.B.equals(myContext)) {
// do something
}
```

In my config for junits I have it set to return a specific value of ContextEnum, like so:

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class myJunitConfig {
    @Bean
    public ContextEnum getContextEnum() {
       return ContextEnum.A;
    }
}
```

My Junit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    myJunitConfig.class
})
public class ContextTest {

  @Test
  public void testContextB() {
      Input input = createMock(Input.class);
      expect(input.getId()).return(1L).anyTimes();
      client.getHandle().call();
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't allow me to test different values of my enum. Is there some way for me to inject different enum values outside of using a setter/constructor injection on the junit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [@Theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories) in conjunction with Spring's [TestContextManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextManager.html)